# Log format not recognised - PhpStorm - Ideolog

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I am using MAMP + PhpStorm + Wordpress. Ideolog says my log format is not recognized. Help me configure it, please.

My log format :

```php
[06-Feb-2020 15:42:09 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1633
[06-Feb-2020 15:42:09 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[06-Feb-2020 15:42:09 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:0
[06-Feb-2020 15:42:09 UTC] PHP   2. require_once() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:22
[06-Feb-2020 15:42:09 UTC] PHP   3. require_once() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-load.php:37
[06-Feb-2020 15:42:09 UTC] PHP   4. require_once() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-config.php:92
[06-Feb-2020 15:42:09 UTC] PHP   5. require_wp_db() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-settings.php:116
[06-Feb-2020 15:42:09 UTC] PHP   6. wpdb->__construct() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-includes/load.php:425
[06-Feb-2020 15:42:09 UTC] PHP   7. wpdb->db_connect() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:632
[06-Feb-2020 15:42:09 UTC] PHP   8. mysqli_real_connect() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1633
[06-Feb-2020 16:37:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server&#8217;s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/forums/">support forums</a>. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-includes/update.php on line 388
[06-Feb-2020 16:37:19 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[06-Feb-2020 16:37:19 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-admin/plugins.php:0
[06-Feb-2020 16:37:19 UTC] PHP   2. require_once() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-admin/plugins.php:10
[06-Feb-2020 16:37:19 UTC] PHP   3. do_action() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php:367
[06-Feb-2020 16:37:19 UTC] PHP   4. WP_Hook->do_action() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:478
[06-Feb-2020 16:37:19 UTC] PHP   5. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:312
[06-Feb-2020 16:37:19 UTC] PHP   6. wp_update_plugins() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:288
[06-Feb-2020 16:37:19 UTC] PHP   7. trigger_error() /Volumes/Workspace/Mamp/wordpress/wp-includes/update.php:388
```

Ideolog settings. I think I need to enter some regular expressions.

[image]

Comment: This feature seems half baked or worst, totally broken. I have tried countless regexps that check out fine on online regex checkers but end up totally useless in phpstorm.

Comment: I suggest for you to use `https://regex101.com/` to assist you to extract your regex

Comment: @Ejaz yeah, same problem here with simple pipe separated log file: "log format not recognized". Even the standard idea logs won't work, despite being included out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have. It's not perfect, but it works.

Log Format:

- Message pattern: `^\[([^]]+)\s*America/Denver\]\s+([\w\s]+)[.:]\s+(.+)$` (Change "America/Denver" to your timezone, or replace with a more generic regex)
- Message start pattern: `^\[`
- Time format: `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`
- Time capture group: `1`
- Severity capture group: `2`
- Category capture group: `0`
- Apply message pattern to all message lines: `unchecked`

Patterns: (You can use your own highlighting scheme)

- `^\s*(?:PHP\s*)?e(rror)?\s*$`
- `^\s*(?:PHP\s*)?w(arn(ing)?)?\s*$`
- `^\s*(?:PHP\s*)?i(nfo)?\s*$`
- `^\s*(?:PHP\s*)?n(otice)?\s*$`
- `^\s*(?:PHP\s*)?f(?:atal(?:\s*error)?)?\s*$`

It still doesn't collapse the stack traces, and Ideolog seems to make the file read only within PhpStorm, so deleting log contents is cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would need to dive into Ideolog configuration on your own: there's no out-of-the box solution for PHP/WP error log it seems, see https://github.com/JetBrains/ideolog/issues/49. You might want to start from https://github.com/JetBrains/ideolog/issues/42.